# Java - Hibernate not inserting all array values

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm having an issue with Hibernate where it doesn't insert all array values. However, if I change the array to a list, it does insert all list values. This is my array mapping:

```xml
<component name="component" access="field">
    <many-to-one name="parent" class="Parent" insert="false" update="false" fetch="join" column="id" access="field"/>
    <array name="entries" table="component_entry" cascade="all-delete-orphan" access="field">
        <key column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
        <index column="index" type="int"/>
        <one-to-many class="ComponentEntry"/>
    </array>
</component>
```

My classes look like this:

```java
class Parent {
    private Component component;
}

class Component {
    private Parent parent;
    private ComponentEntry[] entries;
}

class ComponentEntry {
    private int id;
    private Component parent;
    private int valueOne;
    private int valueTwo;
    private double valueThree;
}
```

If I add 25 entries in a `Component` instance and save the `Parent` entity, Hibernate will only create one insert query. Now, if I would change the `entries` field type to a `List` and update the mapping like this:

```xml
<component name="skills" access="field">
    <many-to-one name="parent" class="Parent" insert="false" update="false" fetch="join" column="id" access="field"/>
    <list name="entries" table="component_entry" cascade="all-delete-orphan" access="field">
        <key column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
        <list-index column="index" type="int"/>
        <one-to-many class="ComponentEntry"/>
    </list>
</component>
```

Hibernate will create 25 insert queries. My question: why does Hibernate not insert all values when using an array?

Edit:
I ensured multiple times that all values in the `entries` field are **not null**.